# elasticsearch can it use NUMA on x86-64 linux architecture?

Tags: elasticsearch

I know mongodb recommend NUMA in linux to be disabled for mongod  , but is this the case for elasticsearch as well , please, advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, [NUMA is irrelevant](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/399) for Elasticsearch as long as you enable [memory](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_memory_lock_check.html) [locking](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration-memory.html#bootstrap-memory_lock), which is a prerequisite for running Elasticsearch in production.

Comment: this is very old article from 2010 , not very sure if this is still valid in 2021?

Comment: Somewhere in the net few months ago: Try to pick more recent Java as it’s tuned to run better on NUMA machines, still not all of JVM is NUMA-aware

Comment: other article: https://vinted.engineering/2017/09/18/elasticsearch-more-nodes-with-fewer-servers/

Comment: another article also interesting: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-do-performance-benchmark-elasticsearch-on-a-large-single-node-bare-metal-server/160965

Comment: It is definitely valid as memory locking is still the official way to do it